# Recover cs50: It recovered 000.jpg but when i run it again without making any changes with check50. It didnt work?

Tags: cs50, recover

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("./recover file_name\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("This file cannot be opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    //512B is the size of 1 block
    unsigned char buffer[512];
    FILE *img = NULL;
    
    //we alr know that there is 50 images for us to recover
    string filename[50];
    int count = 0;
    
    // read 1 element of 512B into buffer array
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 512, file) == 512 *sizeof(unsigned char))
    {
        //NEW jpeg
        if (img == NULL)
        {
            //start of jpeg
            if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                //create filename(string not array) for new file
                sprintf(filename[count], "%03i.jpg", count);
                
                //create new jpeg file with new filename & write/append in card.raw
                img = fopen(filename[count],"w");
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
                fclose(img);
            }
            //continue while loop and read file if cannot find jpeg signature
        }
        else
        {
            //Discover jpeg signature
            //End of jpeg + Start of new jpeg
            if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                fclose(img);
                //intialize pointer
                img = NULL;
                count++;
                
                //create filename(string not array) for new file
                sprintf(filename[count], "%03i.jpg", count);
                
                //create new jpeg file with new filename & write/append in card.raw
                img = fopen(filename[count],"w");
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
            }
            else
            {
                //continue writing to jpeg file
                fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!feof(file))
    {
        printf("Unknown error occured\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("%i jpeg images recovered\n", count);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

**UndefinedBehaviourSanitizer: DEADLYSIGNAL
The signal is caused by WRITE memory access
Hint:address points to zero page**

What's the problem? I can't seem to figure it out.
Is it a logic problem?
It recovered 000.jpg but when i run it again without making any changes with check50(at least I don't think I made any changes). It didnt work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is: one should only use the `string` datatype if it will be populated by `get_string`. I don't think it is explicitly mentioned in the course material, but because of memory allocation, it will not work otherwise. Since the 50 elements of `filename` do not get properly allocated, there will be unpredictable results.

Consider this: Does `filename` need to be an array of strings? Is there any reason to "keep" all the file names? Each will be used exactly once, and not needed again. If `filename` was an array of *chars*, it would suffice. It would have to be declared with enough bytes to accomodate a file name and the terminating null byte.

While this `//we alr know that there is 50 images for us to recover` is true for the raw file contained in the distro code, it is unnecessarily limiting. What if the grading program used a raw file that only contained 10 photos, or contained 100 photos?

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know that the problem was with the string part.